# Rakesh says to sajani...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Rakesh says to sajani, "I am twice as old as you were when I was as old as you are.". If the sum of their present ages is 49 years, find the present ages.

My attempt. 
Let the present age of Rakesh be $x$ years and the present age of Sajani be $y$ years.

According to question:.
$$x=2[y-(x-y)]$$.

Also,
$x+y=49$.

Is my statement correct according to the condition given in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Now all you have to do is solve it for $x $ and $y $!

I will break it down for other people that read my answer.

Rakesh says "I am twice as old as you were when I was as old as you are."

Let $x $ be how old Rakesh is and $y $ the age of Sajani.

We know that $x + y = 49$.

Now we parse Rakesh's sentence bit by bit! "I am twice as old".

Because he says *"am"*, the present tense, he is talking about his age today, which is $x $. He says that age is twice some number. Therefore

$$x = 2 \times [ some\ number ] $$

The *"as you were"* indicates that we are going to talk about Sajani's age some time ago. Note that Sajani's age, *"some time ago"* is given by $y - (how\ many\ years\ passed) $

So we just have to check how much time has passed. And then they say *"when I was as old as you are"*. So when was Rakesh as old as Sajani is? Sajani is $y $ years old and Rakesh is $x $ so if from $x $ we subtract $(x-y) $ we get $y $ that is, $x-y $ years ago Rakesh was as old as Sajani is. Then we look back at *"as old as you were **some time ago**"*. We know that **some time ago** is $x-y $, so $x-y $ years ago Sajani was $y - (x - y) $ years old. Now we plug this as the *"some number"* to get

$$x = 2 \times [y - (x - y)] $$

Simplifying we get

$$x = 2 (2y + x) \iff x = 4y - 2x \iff 3x = 4y \iff \frac {3}{4}x = y$$
But $$x + y = 49 \iff x + \frac {3}{4}x = 49 \iff \frac {7}{4}x = 49 \iff x = \frac {4}{7}49 = 28$$

And it follows that $y = 21$.

Comment: When I solved this question, I got the answers as $x=28 years $ and $y=21 years$. But the answer in my book are $29.4. and 19.6$ years respectively. Which one is correct?

Comment: @user354073 Yours is . Their answer was correct if the left hand side had been $y $ instead of $x $.